# Want to check that $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}w^{ jm}=0$, $m\not\equiv 0 \pmod{k}$ where $w=e^{2\pi i/k}$

Tags: power-series, special-functions, proof-explanation

> If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$, then 
>   $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{kn+m}x^{kn+m}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}w^{-jm}f(w^j x) \tag{1},$$
>   where $w=e^{2\pi i/k}$ is a primitive $k$th root of unity. This is a consequence of $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}w^{ jm}=0$, $m\not\equiv 0 \pmod{k}$.

This is taken a proof from [Special Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521623219) page 14. I want to verify $(1)$. I suppose the series of $f(x)$ is convergent, and we rewrite the $(1)$ as follows

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{kn+m}x^{kn+m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}w^{j(n-m)}}_{=:\,p(n)}a_{n}x^n.$$
If $n=\ell k+m$ for all $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$, then 
$$p(\ell k+m)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}w^{j\ell k}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}1^{j}=1.$$ I think the last sentence in the quote says that if $n\neq \ell k+m$ for all $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $p(n)=0$. But I am not sure how to check it in general.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Why the equality  $\;\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \omega^{jm}=0\;$ is true, or what, please?

Comment: @Joanpemo Yes, I want to know why it is true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051380/how-to-prove-sum-of-powers-property-of-roots-of-unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\;\omega\;$ is a root of $\;x^k-1\;$ and, in fact, of the $\;k-$th cyclotomic polynomial:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\omega^m\right)^j\stackrel{\text{geom. sum}}=\frac{1-\omega^{mk}}{1-\omega^m}=0\;,\;\;\text{because}\;\;\omega^{mk}=\left(\omega^k\right)^m=1\;\;\text{and}\;\;\omega^m\ne1$$

Why the condition $\;m\neq0\pmod k\;?$  Because otherwise

$$m=lk\implies \omega^m=\left(\omega^k\right)^l=1\implies\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\omega^m\right)^j=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}1=k$$

Also, if $\;\omega^m=1\;$ we cannot for sure use the formula we used above in the first equality.

Comment: @Did Thank you very much for the edit.

Comment: You are welcome. Nice answer.