# Evaluate sum over primitive root mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

Let $r$ be a primitive root of unity mod $p$. $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$ with $1 + x \not\equiv 0$ (mod $p$). I recently came across the sum:

$$
\sum_{y = 0}^{p-1} r^{y(1 + x)} = p 
$$

How do I derive this identity? The geometric sum would equal:

$$
\frac{r^{p(1+x)} - 1}{r^{1+x} - 1}
$$

I'm stuck how this equal $p$. Any hints that help me here?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that in the sum you are supposed to have $y$ range from $1$ to $p-1$ or from $0$ to $p-2$. Otherwise one term is repeated. And $r^{p-1}\equiv1$, so with that fix in place your numerator will be $\equiv0\pmod p$. Also you want $x$ not to be a multiple of $p-1$. After all the exponents should be integers, not elements of $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051380/how-to-prove-sum-of-powers-property-of-roots-of-unity