# Are there $x_n$'s and $y_n$'s such that $\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-i2m\pi x_n}=\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-i2m\pi y_n}$ for $1\geq x_n>y_n\geq0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I am looking for the unique values of $x_n$ and $y_n$ ($n=1,\dots,N$) where $1\geq x_n>y_n\geq0$ such that the folloiwng holds
$$
\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-i2m\pi x_n}=\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-i2m\pi y_n}
$$
for all non-zero integers $0<m\leq N-1$.
I think there is a connection to the [property of the roots of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051380/how-to-prove-sum-of-powers-property-of-roots-of-unity) (their sum equals $0$) but I am not sure how to utilize it.

**Edit:**

Another requirement is that the values of $x_n-y_n$ should be unique for all $n$.

Comment: The question is weird posed: if you take $x_{n}=y_{n}=1$ then you are done.

Comment: It can not be the case though. I am looking for unique values. Also, $x_n>y_n$.

Comment: Adding conditions that totally change the question after someone has posted doesn’t invite one to answer your questions.

Comment: The case where $x_n-y_n$ is the same for all $n$ leads to duplicate of the post I linked to in the original post. I assumed one would not consider that case for this question.